# One To Many Relationship - Cascading Delete

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I'm using EF 4.1 where I'm trying to map my POCO to my existing database. This is working fine until I try to delete an item that the other item has a dependency to. I want to enable cascading deletes, so that when my first item is deleted all dependencies would also be deleted (I believe this is called cascading delete).

I tried to enable this in the OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Component>()
         .HasMany(c => c.Specifications)
         .WithRequired(s => s.Component)
         .Map(m => m.MapKey("ComponentId"))
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

However, I still get the `The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint` exception.

The database is quite simple:

**Component**:

```
ComponentId (PK)
Description
```

**Specification**:

```
SpecificationID (PK)
Description
ComponentID (FK)
```

I've created the two following classes to match this setup:

```
public class Specification
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Component Component { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Component
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Specification> Specifications { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you recreate the database after you added cascading rule? Check in your database that relation really have cascade rule defined.

Comment: I do not have the option to recreate the DB since it already exists. Would EF cascading delete require this rule to be enabled?

Comment: I enabled cascading delete on the relationship in the database, and then everything started to work as I would expect. Rewrite your comment as an answer and I'll mark it :)

Comment: If you do not recreate db you cannot expect that EF will make necessary changes for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cascading delete in your model *requires* cascading delete in your DB. If you let the EF recreate the DB for you, it will set this up automatically. If you cannot let the EF do this, then you must either:

1. Add cascading delete to the FK manually, or
2. Remove the cascade from the model.